# ¿Cómo guardar un BufferedImage como una imagen png en Java?

Tags: java, imagen

Me refiero a cargar una imagen que se encuentre en el proyecto con un  BufferedImage asi:

```
BufferedImagen imagen = ImageIO.read(new File("imagen.png"));
```

y luego esa imagen guardarla en el escritorio asignandole un nombre desde codigo, no necesito que me expliquen sobre seleccionar la ruta con un JFileChooser ni nada, solo la instruccion, que sea algo como recibir la imagen, la ruta en donde sera guardada y el nombre del archivo que se va a crear.

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun tu ejemplo guardar la imagen seria asi:

```
File outputfile = new File("../desktop/nuevoNombre.png");
ImageIO.write(imagen, "png", outputfile);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me ha funcionado a la perfección, eso era lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

En primero lugar, se debe crear una imagen en memoria sobre la que podamos dibujar. Para ellos se usa BufferedImage. El código puede ser así

```
 BufferedImage imagen = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

donde 100, 100 son el ancho y alto en pixels para nuestra imagen, y el tercer parámetro indica cómo queremos que sea esa imagen. En nuestro ejemplo, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB representa una imagen con pixels de 8 bits en RGB.

Una vez obtenido el BufferedImage, le pedimos el Graphics para poder dibujar

```
// Hacemos el dibujo
Graphics g = imagen.getGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
g.setColor(Color.green);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
g.setColor(Color.yellow);
g.fillOval(25, 25, 50, 50);
```

Finalmente, sólo nos queda salvar la imagen en el fichero

```
try {
   ImageIO.write(imagen, "jpg", new File("foto.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Error de escritura");
}
```

Los formatos en los que se puede grabar son bmp, jpg, wbmp, jpeg, png, gif, que son los que obtenemos con el siguiente trozo de código

```
for (String posibleFormato : ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes())
   System.out.println(posibleFormato);
```

Fuente: [guardar Imagen](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Guardar_imagen_en_fichero)

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por tu respuesta!, Saludos.